# Copy files from path to path same structure for each user

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, centos

How to copy single file for example index.html

from source

```
/backup/cpbackup/daily/a1/homedir/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/b2/homedir/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/c3/homedir/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/d4/homedir/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/e5/homedir/public_html/index.html
/backup/cpbackup/daily/f6/homedir/public_html/index.html
```

to destination

```
/home/a1/public_html/index.html
/home/b2/public_html/index.html
/home/c3/public_html/index.html
/home/c4/public_html/index.html
/home/e5/public_html/index.html
/home/f6/public_html/index.html
```

cp command can't do this to copy all files to the same directory for each user , so how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a shell loop (copy/paste this into a terminal window):

```
for user in a1 b2 c3 c4 e5 f6; do
 cp -p "/backup/cpbackup/daily/$user/homedir/public_html/index.html" \
    "/home/$user/public_html/";
done
```

The `-p` flag makes `cp` preserve the attributes (owner,group, timestamp) of the copied files.

If you want to do this for *all* users (i.e. all sub directories of `/backup/cpbackup/daily/`) you can do something like this which avoids manually entering the usernames:

```
for dir in /backup/cpbackup/daily/*; do user=$(basename $dir);
    cp -p "/backup/cpbackup/daily/$user/homedir/public_html/index.html" \
    "/home/$user/public_html/";
done
```

Comment: i got cp: cannot stat `/backup/cpbackup/daily-bak//home/a1/homedir/public_html/index.php': No such file or directory --- this is the output from the 2nd command i want to do for all users

Comment: @iLinux85 yes, sorry, my bad, the second example includes `/home/$user` and that is not what you need. What exactly do you want to do? Do you really want to run this for all users?

Comment: @iLinux85 see updated answer, that will still give you an error message for directories like `/home/lost+found` (you can safely ignore it) but it should work for the rest.

Comment: there is no error after u update the command but there is no files copied from source to destination the output is
cp /backup/cpbackup/daily/a1/homedir/public_html/index.html /home/a1/public_html/

Comment: @iLinux85 can we continue this in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10863/room-for-terdon-and-ilinux85)?